# How to float a div At top - and push other divs down?

Tags: javascript, css

I feel like this is a really dumb question, but everything I've read just isn't getting through to how I can use it.  I want to have a very basic page with two `div`s.  One on top with overall information and one on the bottom with all the data.  When the data is longer than the page and the user scrolls, I want the top div to float down.  I get that to happen by using `position: fixed` and `top: 0`, but the first `div` doesn't push the second down.

I could, of course, add `margin-top` to the data `div`, but I also want to be able to toggle the top `div` on/off.  When I do that (toggle it off), the `margin-top` remains, so it's clearly a bit of a hack.

How can I keep a floating `div` on top and push everything else down?

Here's an example showing the basics of what I'm struggling with:

https://jsfiddle.net/vxf5dh7j/

HTML:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="topFloat">
      BANNER TYPE STUFF
    </div>
    <div id="data">
      test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#topFloat {
  border:1px black solid;
  position:fixed;
  top: 0;
}
#data {
  border: 1px red solid;
}
```

Comment: Your requirements contradict one another. 1) *I want the top div to float down* 2) *push other divs down*

Comment: soulshined - I can understand that.  What I'm wanting is for the data to be offset from the top of the screen by the presence of the banner.  Like this page, and how the stackoverflow search box stay on top.  But I don't want to simply use top-margin because I will also have a toggle to hide the banner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```css
#topFloat {
  border:1px black solid;
  position:sticky;
  top: 0;
}
#data {
  border:1px red solid;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="topFloat">
      BANNER TYPE STUFF
    </div>
    <div id="data">
      test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I want the "BANNER TYPE STUFF" div to stay on top as the user scrolls though.  On top being, at the top of the browser page, which position: fixed achieves.

Comment: I knew it would be something simple.  I haven't used sticky before.  It looks like your code snippet isn't working though because of a miss paste (I think).  If you fix that, I can accept your answer.  Thanks!

Comment: It is working. If you can't run the snippet like i do, copy the code and paste it in your own code, and you'll see that's working. I'm glad i could help you.